# How to show count of sub elements in Group By query - Pivoted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have cars table.
It has marques:

- Nissan
- Toyota
- BMW

We have cities:

- New York
- Los Angeles
- Dallas

Table:

- Id
- Marque
- CityId

It has all 250 000 cars for the 3 cities.

How do we show them grouped by city and count, but the cities are columns.

This is my query:

```
SELECT Count(veh.id) [Count],pd.District, vet.Name  FROM Vehicles veh

INNER JOIN PostalDistricts pd on pd.Id = veh.PostalDistrictId
INNER JOIN VehicleMarqueId vet on vet.id = veh.VehicleMarqueId

GROUP BY pd.District, vet.Name

ORDER BY Count(veh.id) DESC, pd.District asc
```

But the result is:

```
+-------+-------------+--------+
| Count |    City     | Marque |
+-------+-------------+--------+
|  9547 | New York    | Toyota |
|  3509 | Dallas      | Toyota |
|  2608 | Los Angeles | Toyota |
|  2545 | New York    | Nissan |
|  2107 | Dallas      | Nissan |
|  1780 | Los Angeles | Nissan |
+-------+-------------+--------+
```

Expected is:

```
+-------------+--------+--------+
|    City     | Toyota | Nissan |
+-------------+--------+--------+
| Dallas      |   3509 |   2107 |
| Los Angeles |   2608 |   1780 |
| New York    |   9547 |   2545 |
+-------------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: Please see my query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `pivot` statement:

```
declare @tmp table ([count] int , City varchar(50), Marque nvarchar(50))

insert into @tmp values
 (9547, 'New York', 'Toyota')
,(3509, 'Dallas', 'Toyota')
,(2608, 'Los Angeles', 'Toyota')
,(2545, 'New York', 'Nissan')
,(2107, 'Dallas', 'Nissan')
,(1780, 'Los Angeles', 'Nissan')

select * from @tmp
pivot 
( 
    max([count]) 
    for Marque in ([Toyota], [Nissan] ) 
) piv
```

Results:

[image]

But if you have more values in the `Marque` column you have to use dynamic TSQL to generate all the columns needed

Comment: Good news is that the count is fixed, 3 types only, so that should allow the pivot usage. I will give it a try now.